Adding an image in shopify tabs
This is in snippets/tab.liquid
{%- liquid
  assign output_tab = true
  if title == blank and content == blank
    assign output_tab = false
  endif
-%}
{%- if output_tab -%}
  <div class="collapsibles-wrapper collapsibles-wrapper--border-bottom">
    <button type="button"
      class="label collapsible-trigger collapsible-trigger-btn collapsible-trigger-btn--borders collapsible--auto-height{% if force_open %} is-open{% endif %}" aria-controls="Product-content-{{ id }}"
      {% if force_open %}aria-expanded="true"{% endif %}>
      {{ title }}
      {%- render 'collapsible-icons' -%}
    </button>
    <div id="Product-content-{{ id }}"
      class="collapsible-content collapsible-content--all{% if force_open %} is-open{% endif %}"
      {% if force_open %}style="height: auto;"{% endif %}>
      <div class="collapsible-content__inner rte">
        {{ content }}
    

This is the code that I have added
{% assign image_url = product.metafields.custom.fit_guide_image %}
{% if image_url != blank %} 
 <img src="{{ image_url.value | image_url }}">
{% endif %}

on the tabs, the image appears in every tab
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{%- endif -%}

This is snippets/product-template.liquid
 {%- when 'tab' -%}
                {% assign tab_id = block.id | append: product.id %}
                {% capture tab_content %}
                  {{ block.settings.content }}
                  {{ block.settings.page.content }}
                {% endcapture %}
                {% unless tab_content == blank and block.settings.title == blank %}
                  <div class="product-block product-block--tab tansyo2" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                    {%- render 'tab', id: tab_id, title: block.settings.title, content: tab_content -%}
                  </div>
                {% endunless %}

I just want it to show on that particular tab, because currently it shows on all tabs, anyone please help
